# AS3 Live Update Load external text

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to constantly reload data from a text file on a website, and make that data the .x property of a movieclip. Like this:

```
 movieclip.x = int(externallyLoadedData);
```

I know how to do this, but I want it so I can ftp rewrite the text file with a different number, and the flash movie updates live without having to refresh/restart. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My choice would be to use a Timer to reload the data from the text file every 100 miliseconds or so.

```
public function Constructor(){    
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(100); //how often will the data be reloaded
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, refreshPage);
    timer.start();
}

private function refreshPage(e:TimerEvent):void {
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("test.txt"));
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, displaytext);
}

private function displaytext(e:Event):void {
    mc.x = int((e.currentTarget as URLLoader).data);
}
```

Of course, the implementation depends on what you need specifically in your application.